# Angular: Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting two error messages:
**Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

and

**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ActsController' is not a function, got undefined**

I'm assuming my ActsController.js file is failing to load. However, I have other controller files that are loading just fine. It's only this one that's causing trouble.

*app.js*

```
var snowball_effect = angular.module('snowball_effect', [
    'templates', 
    'ngRoute', 
    'ngResource',
    'controllers'
]);

snowball_effect.config([
  '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    return $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: "static_pages/templates/index.html",
      controller: 'StaticPagesController'
    })
    .when('/acts/index', {
      templateUrl: "acts/templates/index.html",
      controller: 'ActsController'
    })
    .when('/acts/:id', {
      templateUrl: "acts/templates/show.html",
      controller: 'ActsController'
    });
  }
]);

var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
```

*acts/controllers/ActsController.js*

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers');

controllers.controller('ActsController', [
  '$scope', 
  '$routeParams', 
  '$location', 
  '$resource', 
  function($scope,$routeParams,$location,$resource) {
    $scope.acts = [
      {
        id: 1, 
        name: "Plant a Flower", 
        description: "Plant a flower in your garden or along the street.",
        inspires: 1
      }
    ];

    $scope.addAct = function() {
      $scope.acts.push($scope.newAct);
    }

    $scope.deleteAct = function(act) {
      $scope.acts.splice($scope.acts.indexOf(act), 1);
    }

    $scope.linkToShowAct = function(act) {
      $location.path('acts/' + act.id);
    }
}]);
```

*acts/templates/index.html*

```
<div class="actions_body">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Listing Actions</h2>

    <div ng-controller="ActsController" class="body">
      <table class="row">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 active">
              <label>Name</label>
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Description</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Inspires</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="col-md-2">Modify</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="act in acts">
          <td class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2"><a href="" ng-click="linkToShowAct(act)">{{act.name}}</a></td>
          <td class="col-md-4">{{act.description}}</td>
          <td class="col-md-2">{{act.inspires}}</td>
          <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
          <td><button ng-click="deleteAct(act)">Delete</a></button>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <br>

      <button ng-click="newActShow=true">New Action</button>
      <button ng-click="newActShow=false">Hide</button>

      <div ng-show="newActShow" id="newAct">
        <div class="row">
          <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="addAct()">
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
              <label for="newActname">Name</label>
              <input type="text" ng-model="newAct.name" id="newActname" placeholder="Name" class="form-control col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
              <label for="newActdescription">Description</label>
              <input type="textarea" ng-model="newAct.description" id="newActdescription" placeholder="Description" class="form-control col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
              <label for="newActinspires">Inspires</label>
              <input type="number" ng-model="newAct.inspires" id="newActinspires" placeholder="Inspires" class="form-control col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*acts/templates/show.html*

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ActsController">
    <div class="body">

        <h1>
            {{acts[0].name}}
        </h1>

        <p class="act-show-description">
            {{acts[0].description}}
        </p>

        <p class="act-show-inspires">
            <strong>Inspires:</strong>
            {{acts[0].inspires}}
        </p>

        <a href="#/">Edit</a>
        <a href="#/">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, my other controllers are working just fine. For example:

*application/controllers/NavBarController.js*

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers');

controllers.controller("NavBarController", [
  '$scope', 
  '$routeParams', 
  '$location',
  function($scope,$routeParams,$location) {

    $scope.actsIndex = function() {
      $location.path("/acts/index");
    }

    $scope.actsNew = function () {
      $location.path("/acts/index");
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Try removing the line `controllers = angular.module('controllers');` in your NavBarController.js file. It might be overwriting your initial 'controllers' module with the new one (and thereby replacing the ActsController)

Comment: Hm, that didn't solve the problem. 

But how can I access the NavBarController if I remove the controller variable. According to the Angular docs, controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);  would override the original module. But without the brackets, it simply invokes the original.

Comment: can you show the order that your scripts are being loaded in your HTML?

Comment: Have you imported acts/controllers/ActsController.js  in your index.html? Some time we just forget to include the new javascript file :)

Comment: Think you could throw this up  on a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/)?

Comment: [Made one myself](http://plnkr.co/edit/xw2ys3PWE1szgnROPKJo). Nothing wrong with the controller code (Stripped out a few services that I didn't load the files for and weren't being utilized) Looks to me like you're loading ActsController.js before loading app.js which is important in this case because you're defining the module `controllers` in app, then later recalling it through angular in ActsController. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module#usage

Comment: Hm well I'm making a rails app, and rails automatically wraps everything in the assets pipeline (ie, css and javascript files) in self-executing functions. In other words, all of these files should be executed automatically, without having to import them in the index. But it's very possible that app.js is loading before ActsController.js. I'm not so sure how I should deal with this...

Comment: Ok, figured out how to rearrange the order in which files are executed (apparently it defaults to alphabetical), and you were exactly right. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your acts/templates/index.html try adding the controller script. Check if that fixes the loading issue.

```
<script src="scripts/controllers/ActsController.js"></script>
```

Also inside acts/controllers/ActsController.js file try creating a simpler version of the controller first.

```
angular.module('controllers')
  .controller('ActsController', function () {
   // something simpler 
  });
```