# Angular controller in separated files does not work

Tags: angularjs

Why a controller does not work in separated files?

Application structure:

[See app structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdEBH.jpg)

**store.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="userController">
            <h1>{{user.firstname}}</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="/static/app/user/userController.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/app/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
   app.controller("myContoller",["$scope",function ($scope) {
}]);
```

**userController.js**

```
app.controller("userController",["$scope",function ($scope) {
    $scope.hello= "john doe";
    $scope.user = {
        id:1,
        firstname:"Wojciech"
    }
}]);
```

Comment: if you haven't solved the problem yet, check out my answer (updated ). that should work now

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Based on the comment of @Claies, I updated the answer for future reference.

- You have to change the order of your `script` tags in the *store.html* like this:

**store.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="userController">
            <h1>{{user.firstname}}</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="/static/app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/app/user/userController.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

- And you need to declare `app` in *userController.js* as well, the same way you did in *app.js*.

**userController.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp"); //locate the module first   
app.controller("userController",["$scope",function ($scope) {
        $scope.hello= "john doe";
        $scope.user = {
            id:1,
            firstname:"Wojciech"
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: @user7437694, Are you getting any errors in console? If it doesn't work there must be some traces somewhere. Please take a look at the dev tools in your web browser and share it with us.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:2075
    at b (angular.js:1999)
    at Object.module (angular.js:2073)
    at userController.js:1
(anonymous) @ angular.js:38
(anonymous) @ angular.js:2075
b @ angular.js:1999
(anonymous) @ angular.js:2073
(anonymous) @ userController.js:1

Comment: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?p0=userController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: Well, this can many things. I think, maybe there is a problem with the inclusion/declaration of either your modules/files in your project or some resource (as ngRoute, for instance). (See some questions about this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045416/angular-js-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144661/angular-uncaught-error-injectornomod-module-controllers-is-not-available, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673404/error-ngareq-from-angular-controller).

Comment: @user7437694, also make sure you have all required resources loaded into your project. How are you including the resources (controllers, services, etc) in your project?

Comment: @user7437694 based on the code in the original question, this answer won't work, because you are declaring your `userController.js` script **before** your `app.js` script, so the `userController` can't find `app` since it isn't declared yet.  This answer would be correct, if the order of your scripts were changed as well.

Comment: @Claies, thanks. You're completely right!. I updated the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

source app.js before userController.js

In case you want to define controller in separate file, you can do so. You just need to get your app reference.

userController.js

```
/*
   angular.module call without "[]" returns the app object 
   rather than creating a new app.
*/
var app = angular.module("app"); 
app.controller("ControllerName", ["$scope", function($scope){
    // controller code here.
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

app.js should be refered in the html first before the controllers.

Instead of:

```
<script src="/static/app/user/userController.js"></script>
<script src="/static/app/app.js"></script>
```

Do this:

```
<script src="/static/app/app.js"></script>    
<script src="/static/app/user/userController.js"></script>
```